# React player: Fullscreen mode with custom controls on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I have a component that uses React player to show and control a video. On a desktop browser, all controls work as they should, but only the fullscreen function doesn't work on iOS browsers. As I read about this topic, I see that many had the same problem for showing video in fullscreen mode on iOS. Is there any way how could I make the video go to fullscreen without using the native controls?